# Delphi query component ignores raising error

Tags: delphi

I have a `TADOQuery` component which is connected to an SQL Server database using `TADOConnection`.
Now, when I add below SQL to the component, and call ExecSql its raising proper exception, because there is a typo in the 'Create' word.

```
 exec ('creat1e table myTable 
     (
          col1     TPT_Dt       not null ,
          col2     TPT_FLOAT       not null
     )');
```

But the same statement, if I add it to another statement, then the TADOQuery component ignores this exception. E.g. :

```
 select * from SomeOtherTable where id = 10

 exec ('creat1e table myTable 
     (
          col1     DtDataType       not null ,
          col2     FLOATDataType       not null
     )');
```

Could you please tell me why Delphi ignores the exception in the second case.

my issue is not with the select statement. even if i add an if condition then also same issue ;

for example

```
if not exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id('TABLE1278') and type='U')
begin
 exec ('crea11te table table1278 
     (
          col1     TPT_Dt     
     )');
end
```

delphi simply ignores the typo.

Thanks in advance.

Basil

Comment: I guess because the first statement is successful and ADO returns a dataset along with the related error message(s)

Comment: do you execute `if not exists...` **without** a select first? if yes then I cannot reproduce. if you do you a select before, then I think the issue is with SQL `exec`. if I omit the exec and use `crea11te` statement then an error is raised. Ive tested it with `ADOCinnection.Execute` with `eoExecuteNoRecords` (default) and this should not even try and rerun a recordset like TADOQuery. interesting question anyway.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519912/ado-command-running-multiple-sql-statements-cant-get-error-message-back-use-t) may be related. the [resolution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/254304) provided by Microsoft (`SET NOCOUNT ON`) did not helped for me.

Answer (score 2):

All recordsets generated from a query are returned. The first one will be show by default, with corresponding error.
You can access all recordsets via ADODataSet1.NextRecordset(a).

e.g. you have following query

```
select * from TableWhichExists

Select * from TableWichNotExists
```

You will fetch result of TableWhichExists.

With

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 rs:_RecordSet;
 a:Integer;
begin
  rs := ADODataSet1.NextRecordset(a)
end;
```

you can access the next recordset und will receive the corresponding error.

NextRecordset may be usefull e.g. to receive several recordset via procedure, calculatin once all needed recordset.

To use e.g. three received results you could work like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 a:Integer;
begin
  Adodataset2.Recordset := ADODataSet1.NextRecordset(a) ;
  Adodataset3.Recordset := ADODataSet1.NextRecordset(a)
end;
```

Adodataset1 would display the first result.